# Segmentation fault(core dumped) in C program in ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, segmentation-fault, coredump

I am trying to create a maze game where we create maze with inputs like $ for bonus X for enemy etc.I used * for boundaries. Even though the program works just fine in DEV C++ it throws segmentation fault in C. I just can't see what I am doing wrong and why it works in windows but not in Ubuntu. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   
   int row, column;
   int player_row, player_column, final_row, final_column;
   int total_prize=0;
   int prize;  
   int dolar[50][50];  
   char maze[50][50];
   scanf("%d %d", &row, &column);  
   int i;
   int j;
   for(i=0;i<=row;i++){
           for(j=0;j<=column;j++){
               maze[i][j]='+';
       }
   }
   for(i=0;i<column;i++){
       maze[0][i]='*';
       maze[row-1][i]='*';
   }
   for(j=0;j<row;j++){
       maze[j][0]='*';
       maze[j][column-1]='*';
   }
   int details = 1;
   while(details==1){
       char detail;
       int row, column;
       //scanf("%s %d %d",&detail, &row, &column);
       scanf("%s", &detail);
       if(detail=='s'){
           scanf("%d %d", &row, &column);
           player_row = row;
           player_column = column;
           maze[row][column]='O';
       }
       else if(detail=='f'){
           scanf("%d %d", &row, &column);
           final_row =row;
           final_column = column;
           maze[row][column]=' ';  
       }
       else if(detail=='b'){
           scanf("%d %d", &row, &column);
           maze[row][column]='*';  
       }
       else if(detail=='$'){
           scanf("%d %d %d", &row, &column, &prize);
           //scanf("%d", &prize);
           dolar[row][column]=prize;
           maze[row][column]='$';  
       }
       else if(detail=='X'){
           scanf("%d %d", &row, &column);
           maze[row][column]='X';  
       }
       else if(detail="end"){
           maze[0][0]='*';
           maze[0][1]='*';
           maze[0][2]='*';
           maze[0][3]='*';
           break;  
       }           
   }
       for(i=0;i<=row;i++){
       for(j=0;j<=column;j++){
           if(maze[i][j]=='+'){
               printf(" ");        
           }
           else{
               printf("%c", maze[i][j]);
           }           
       }
       printf("\n");
   }
```

Comment: @KfirVentura it didn't work.

Comment: This cannot work: `if(detail="end")` `detail` is only a single character and cannot be same as a string with 3 characters. Also this is an assignment which will also fail because `detail` cannot hold a pointer.

Comment: Please provide your input. What is `row` and `column`?

Comment: This is also wrong: `scanf("%s", &detail);` You must provide address of a string. `detail` can hold 0 characters as it is already needed for terminating 0 byte. You might want to read a single char which is done using `%c`.

Comment: BTW: Some of these bugs should have been reported by your compiler. If not, turn up warning level. If they were reported, do not ignore compiler warnings

Comment: @Gerhardh row and column can be anything between 1-50

Comment: are they including 50?

Comment: yes 50 is included

Comment: Then this is writing out of bounds: `for(i=0;i<=row;i++){` Valid index must be in range 0..49

Comment: when ı used gdb it shows 'if(maze[i][j]=='+'{'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231574/discussion-between-gerhardh-and-barissenol).

Comment: Compile your C code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Read the documentation of your compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation faults are due to an invalid use of a pointer. Here is a good (terrible) example:

```
int *ptr = 0;
*ptr = 17;
```